# Connecting java to Active-Directory - Error 49 data 5

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to connect to AD (2012 R2) from java (8u241) and I am getting this error

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 5, v2580 ]
```

The error is 49, this means wrong user/pass. But this can also mean the login was blocked. I found that out using app called ADExplorer (from sysinternals.com, Microsft): [My Issue On ServerFault - Login blocked for using the ip instead of the name](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011331/active-directory-blocks-ldap-connections-from-other-hosts). Active-Directory will reply with wrong user/pass when the host is an ip instead of the Domain-Name.

The sub error code is 5. I have not found any documentation about this code 5 anywhere.
(NOT 52e. I get 52e when I enter a wrong username)

What is this error (LDAP Err 49 data 5) and how can I fix it?

My Code:

```
public void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("UseOfObsoleteCollectionType")
    java.util.Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new java.util.Hashtable<>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    String url = "LDAP://" + serverName.toUpperCase()+ '.' + domainName.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("url = '" + url + "'");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);

    String sp = takeUntil(domainName.toUpperCase(), '.') + "\\" + username;
    System.out.println("sp = '" + sp + "'");

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, sp);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env); // javax.naming.AuthenticationException here
    ctx.close();
}
```

Result (Excuted in the server - Win Server 2012 R2):

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>java -jar ActiveDirectory.jar array.is blackhole ARRAY\muaaz P0987654321q
url = 'LDAP://BLACKHOLE.ARRAY.IS'
sp = 'ARRAY\muaaz'
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 5, v2580 ]
```

Comment: Try a different user for login.

Comment: Same result for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the OS, and installing another build.

Answer (score 0):

The number after "data" is Windows system error code, which you can find in Microsoft documentation. That particular one is on [the first page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-), and mean "access is denied".

That is more of an authorization error rather than authentication. It means "I know who you are and you aren't allowed to do this."

I don't know exactly what circumstances would result in that error. Maybe simple bind is disabled on your domain. Maybe the account you're using has some kind of restrictions. I can't say for sure.